# Bug in PDF with EmpiricalDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

The `PDF` applied to `EmpiricalDistribution` of a set of real plots as zero. Given:

```
points = {0.360656, 0.459016, 0.557377, 0.540984, 0.786885, 0.42623, 0.344262, 0.57377, 0.42623, 0.459016};
```

Then:

```
points // EmpiricalDistribution // 
 Query[{Plot[CDF[#, x], {x, 0, 1}] & , Plot[PDF[#, x], {x, 0, 1}] &}]
```

[image]

Whereas for example `HistogramDistribution` works:

```
points // HistogramDistribution // 
 Query[{Plot[CDF[#, x], {x, 0, 1}] & , Plot[PDF[#, x], {x, 0, 1}] &}]
```

[image]

Known issue or expected behavior due to the discrete set of points? I've also tried with ~10k points with the same result.  One would expect delta spikes located at the input points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't find it a bug. Let us go into deep:

```
points = {0.360656, 0.459016, 0.557377, 0.540984, 0.786885, 0.42623,0.344262, 0.57377,
 0.42623, 0.459016};
pdf = PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[points], x]
```

> 0.1 Boole[0.344262 == x] + 0.1 Boole[0.360656 == x] + 
>    0.2 Boole[0.42623 == x] + 0.2 Boole[0.459016 == x] + 
>    0.1 Boole[0.540984 == x] + 0.1 Boole[0.557377 == x] + 
>    0.1 Boole[0.57377 == x] + 0.1 Boole[0.786885 == x]

In order to draw it, `DiscretePlot` instead of `Plot` should be used.

```
DiscretePlot[pdf, {x, points}]
```

[image]

Comment: With `Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{Min@points, Max@points}, {0, 
   0.2}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.05`, the plot is much more informative.